# Connect PC to domain running on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

This is my first time working with domains, and I was wondering how I would go about connecting a PC that runs on my home network to the domain controller that runs on a Azure Virtual Machine (eg in the cloud).

Also, may be worth noting that I am using Windows Server 2012 R2.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at any documentation? What have you tried? It's best to show what you've investigated and tried first.

Comment: This is almost identical to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980091/setup-a-windows-domain-on-azure-and-have-my-laptop-be-a-part-of-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (although highly not recommended) but you will need a VPN connection for this job.

**Configure a Point-to-Site VPN connection to an Azure Virtual Network**

https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/

Basically:

1. Configure a Virtual Network
2. Make sure your VM with Active Directory is deployed in this Virtual Network
3. Configure Point-To-Site in your Virtual Network
4. Donwload the client and connect your home PC to this VPN
5. Once connected, change your home PC DNS servers to point to your VM private address
6. Join Domain in your Home PC

Of course after restart you would lose your connectivity with the VPN. You have to figure a way to automatically connect on windows start or if you have a router with ipsec support you might be able to keep a Site-to-Site connection always on. Either way, not a recommended scenario.

Answer (score 0):

first, you create a domain(which you already have), second you put the DC and the client in the same network for example 192.168.0.4 can talk with 192.168.0.5. and lastly you add the computer in the domain by typing the domainname into the client. if you are working outside the network you will need a VPN connection since Domains arent something clients can globally connect to.

troubleshooting tips

-can you ping the DC from the client?

-are you in the same network?

-does the client find domain?

hope it helps.